# How to remove top margin from chapter heading in a custom macro?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, margins, chapters, vietnamese

I have created a custom margin for the automation of chapter creation of certain sections of me digitizing a book. I want to be able to remove the top margin from the chapter heading as i feel i wouldn't be needing it. However, I can't do this.
Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
% Packages
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
% The specific macro that I use
\newcommand{\house}[3]{
    \chapter[#1]{#1 \\ #2}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \noindent
    \Large{\textbf{(#3)}}}
\begin{document}
\house{HỌ HỒNG BÀNG}{鴻龐氏}{2879 -- 258 trước Tây lịch}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I've done it.

```
% Title Format
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\Huge\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{10pt}
% Macros
\newcommand{\house}[3]{
    \chapter[#1]{#1 \\ #2}
    \noindent
    \Large{\textbf{(#3)}}}
```